# How to check the content of the string AND the length of it in?

Tags: c#, string

Basically, im trying to write a game something like a jackpot with 3 slots in console. According to user input, user will be awarded. But first, i need the user to write the correct string, if user input it something different, program will re-ask the input. user can enter 3 of the following : 
X , Y , Z, x, y, z and J. 
Some examples of user input : XyZ, XXJ, ZJy...
And i need to check if user input length is 3 characters long, and contains XYZxyzJ using loops and if-else statements. Any help would be appreciated!
Edit : My code looks like this now:

```
string input;
string pattern = @"[xXyYzZJ]+";

// Taking the input from the user and defining variables
input = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

int properLength = input.Length;
bool properInput = Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern);

bool check;
if (properLength == 3)
    check = true;
else
    check = false;

if (properInput == true) ;
else
    properInput = false;

Console.WriteLine(check);    // These 2 are for debugging purposes, will not present in final product

Console.WriteLine(properInput);
```

Now i want to proceed the second part of the game but i struggle getting this code to loop. Any idea how can i loop this piece if booleans properInput and check are true?

Comment: What have you tried so far, what didn't work while it was expected?

Comment: i successfully checked the length of input, using string input; int stringLength = input.Length;
            if (stringLength == 3) , but i struggle in checking them. i used if (input.Contains("XYZ")) but i need to check all of them, and it seems like input.Contains can check only 1 variable. I need to use something like input.Contains("xYz" , "xXJ" ....)

Comment: Alright awesome! If you iterate over the input (`for` or `foreach` loop) you'll end up with each character seperately. Could you see if you can get it working using `Contains`/`IndexOf` this way?

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need something like this

```
var pattern = "^[xXyYzZ]{3}$";  // note new pattern
var input = Console.ReadLine();

while (!Regex.IsMatch(input.Trim(), pattern);)
{
    Console.WriteLine("YOU LOST");
    Console.WriteLine("Do it again");
    input = Console.Readline();        
}

Console.WriteLine("YOU WON");
```

I have not tested it (c#; regex is tested) but it looks correct - you use Regex to make sure only `x`, `y` or `z` are in string and if its 3-long. And then loop until user input is a match

Answer (score -1):

For checking the string length do as below:

```
string text = "abc";
int textLength = text.Length; // Will have value equal 3
```

For checking if the input text contains the specific characters (x, X, y, Y, z, Z and J in your case) use **Regex** (Regular Expression) exists in `System.Text.RegularExpression` namespace. As an example:

```
string text1 = "abc";
string text2 = "XyZ";

string pattern = @"[xXyYzZJ]+";

bool isMatch1 = Regex.IsMatch(text1, pattern); // false
bool isMatch2 = Regex.IsMatch(text2, pattern); // true
```

In this example, isMatch1 will have `false` and isMatch2 will have `true` values.

Comment: edited my question, any further help would be appriciated!

Comment: What is your goal? Is that code work for one case? Now you just want to apply it to more than one iteration?